# Ember View is rendering too early

Tags: ember.js

I have a Route for creating new documents, making a copy of an existing document.

```
App.DocumentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    this.modelParams = params; // save params for reference
    return App.Document.createRecord();
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    // use the params to get our reference document
    var documentModel = App.Document.find(this.modelParams.document_id);

    documentModel.one('didLoad', function () {
      // once loaded, make a serialized copy
      var documentObj = documentModel.serialize();

      // and set the properties to our empty record
      model.setProperties(documentObj);

      console.log('didLoad');
    });
  }
});
```

I added some logs in my View.

```
App.DocumentView = Ember.View.extend({
  init: function () {
    this._super();
    // fires before the didLoad in the router
    console.log('init view');
  },
  willInsertElement: function () {
    // fires before the didLoad in the router
    console.log('insert elem');
  }
});
```

And this is my template

```
{{#if model.isLoaded }}
  {{ view App.DocumentView templateNameBinding="model.slug" class="document portrait" }}
{{ else }}
  Loading...
{{/if}}
```

The problem it seems is that my model `isLoaded`, but not populated when my template is rendered, so the templateNameBinding doesn't exist at this point, and doesn't seem to be updated when the data gets populated.

Should I use something else than model.isLoaded in my template, or should I force a re-render of my template, and if so, how and where? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It seem that you are overcomplicating the things. It should be:</strike>

### EDIT

I misunderstood your question in first read, so

```
App.DocumentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var originalDoc = App.Document.find(params.document_id),
        newDoc = App.Document.createRecord();
        originalDoc.one('didLoad', function () {
             newDoc.setProperties(this.serialize());
        });
        return newDoc;
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

If everything is right, ember will re-render things automatically..

Comment: Ah, it didn't work at first. But when I changed {{#if model.isLoaded }} to {{#if model.slug }} in my template my templateNameBinding started to work. Thanks!